# Change selected items on start of drag in NSOutlineView on Mac

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, selection, nsoutlineview

I have a view based NSOutlineView (written in Objective C) which supports dragging from any row in the tree.  Multiple row selection by the user is not allowed.  I adjust what is being dropped in the **outlineView:acceptDrop:item:childIndex** delegate method to automatically include all necessary parent and child rows.  The actual drag operation works fine.

My issue is with the visual component of what is being dragged.  I can use **outlineView:selectionIndexesForProposedSelection** to modify selections when a selection is made. (My visual select style is **NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone**).  This also works find as the required components are visually represented in the drag.

The problem is that the user does not have to select a row to begin a drag. When a drag commences this way **outlineView:selectionIndexesForProposedSelection** is not called and only the dragged row is displayed during the drag.  The actual drag operation still works as intended.

I've played with all the datasource and delegate methods but I can't seem to find a way to change what is initially dragged so that NSOutlineView will show images for the rows that I include.

It seems as if **outlineView:updateDraggingItemsForDrag** should work but it does not let me change the source of the drag.

It seems as if NSOutlineView's determination of what to highlight during a drag is made based on the selection.  Regardless as to how many items I place on the pasteboard it is always the selected items which are highlighted.

Any ideas as to how to force a selection change on the start of a drag?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that simply subclassing **NSOutlineView** and using **mouseDown** I get in safely before anything else starts.  Setting the selection works fine as the subsequent possible and does not seem to mess up a possible selection change on the same click.